# Finding fundamental set of solutions for this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that the indicial eq. has equal roots. What is the fundamental set of solutions to this equation:

> $$xy''+(1-x )y'-y=0$$

The fact that there are equal roots means that there is only one solution?

Answer (score 2):

Let $y(x)=f(x)\exp(x)$.

This reduces the $2^{\text{nd}}$ order ODE to a first order ODE whose unknown is $f '(x)$.

Comment: Could you please share your insight in finding this transform?

Comment: @Hansen: There is no particular insight. Before trying some traditional methods for solving linear ODE which often are arduous or boring, I use to try a few simple transforms to see if by chance one of them allows a simplification. The transform y(x)=exp(a*x)*f(x) is sometimes fruitfull.

Answer (score 1):

To find the second solution use the formula

> $$ y_2(x) = y_1(x) \ln x + \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^{k+r} , $$

where $y_1$ is the first solution. See [Frobenius Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method#Double_roots).

**Added:** Here is the final answer

> $$ y \left( x \right) = c_1{{\rm e}^{x}}  +c_2e^{x}\,\mathrm{E}_1(x), $$

where $\mathrm{E}_1(z)$ is the exponential integral

> $$ \mathrm{E}_1(z) = \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-tz}}{t}\, dt = \int_0^1 \frac{e^{-z/u}}{u}\, du ,\qquad \Re(z) \ge 0.  $$